# Problems enabling IPv6

Tags: dhcp, ipv6, dhcpv6

I have two Ubuntu Servers on my home network: one acting as a router/gateway (Router), and the other acting as a media/multipurpose server (Server). I've been trying to enable IPv6 on both, but I'm running into problems getting it working on the Server.

**IPv6 works well on the Router, and I can successfully use ping6 to reach ipv6.google.com... but on the Server, I get Network is unreachable errors whenever I try to use ping6.**

For a firewall on both machines, I'm using firewalld. I've added the service "dhcpv6-client" and "dhcpv6" to the relevant zones. I've also set up DHCPv6 on LAN via AdGuardHome.yaml:

```
dhcp:
  enabled: true
  interface_name: enp3s0
  local_domain_name: lan
  dhcpv4:
    gateway_ip: 10.0.0.1
    subnet_mask: 255.255.255.0
    range_start: 10.0.0.2
    range_end: 10.0.0.254
    lease_duration: 86400
    icmp_timeout_msec: 1000
    options: []
  dhcpv6:
    range_start: 2001:db8:100::2
    lease_duration: 86400
    ra_slaac_only: false
    ra_allow_slaac: true
```

...and on the server, I can see that it's getting a local and global IPv6 address via ip -c a:

```
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:bb:c1:d8:6f:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.238/24 metric 100 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic enp3s0
       valid_lft 85023sec preferred_lft 85023sec
    inet6 2001:db8:100::2/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::dabb:c1ff:fed8:6f0d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

However, when I run "ip -6 neigh" on the Router, all of the links are stale (enp3s0 is LAN and enp1s0 is WAN):

```
fe80::10:18ff:febc:bda9 dev enp1s0 lladdr 02:10:18:bc:bd:a9 STALE 
fe80::1af0:e3bf:955e:7922 dev enp3s0 lladdr dc:a6:32:2a:c9:80 STALE 
fe80::221f:3bff:fe6c:ef6e dev enp3s0 lladdr 20:1f:3b:6c:ef:6e STALE 
fe80::d358:7828:fa79:4a97 dev enp3s0 lladdr 38:86:f7:06:bd:21 STALE 
fe80::76d4:23ff:febc:e2be dev enp3s0 lladdr 74:d4:23:bc:e2:be STALE 
fe80::d9c7:c6cc:58c8:1181 dev enp3s0 lladdr 38:86:f7:16:3b:d7 STALE 
fe80::ac9a:b6ff:feec:4a7e dev enp3s0 lladdr ae:9a:b6:ec:4a:7e STALE 
fe80::dabb:c1ff:fed8:6f0d dev enp3s0 lladdr d8:bb:c1:d8:6f:0d STALE 
fe80::5821:7eff:fe1a:2875 dev enp3s0 lladdr 5a:21:7e:1a:28:75 STALE 
fe80::dabb:c1ff:fed8:6f0d dev enp1s0 FAILED 
fe80::201:5cff:fe8e:5646 dev enp1s0 lladdr 00:01:5c:8e:56:46 router STALE 
fe80::22df:b9ff:fe4b:9a8c dev enp3s0 lladdr 20:df:b9:4b:9a:8c STALE 
fe80::7e04:3679:534b:707f dev enp3s0 lladdr e8:84:a5:8f:c4:01 STALE 
fe80::aba:5fff:fec2:5b9c dev enp3s0 lladdr 08:ba:5f:c2:5b:9c STALE 
2001:558:6012:51::1 dev enp1s0 lladdr 00:01:5c:8e:56:46 router STALE
```

IPv6 is not disabled in /etc/sysctl.conf on the Server:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=0
```

/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml on the Server:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
```

/etc/network/interfaces on the Server:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet6 dhcp
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
```

I'm probably overlooking something simple here, since I'm new to IPv6. Any help that anyone could provide in sorting this problem out would be greatly appreciated!